# In Tcl, how to read in file by line and find a list of string (from another file) then append the line with a ##

Tags: regex, tcl, regexp-replace

I need to be able tp read in  file by line and find a set of strings (from another file) that starts with the strings plus set of characters like ({ somedata }) then append the line with a ## to that block.

Here is what I have so far:

```
set mydir <path to my dir>
#file name file.txt with content:
~>cat file.txt
Strng00  {
   some data 
}

Strng021  {
   some data 
}

Strng02  {
   some data 
}

Strng03  {
   some data 
}

Strng_dt  {
   some data 
}

Strng01 {
   some data 
}
Strng02  {
   some data 
}

Strng03  {
   some data 
}

Strng_dt  {
   some data 
}

Strng42  {
   some data 
}

Strng412 
-- 
set list { Strng01 Strng02 Strng03 Strng_dt Strng42 } # May be read in the list from another file which needs to be matched
set fileIn [lindex $argv 0]
set fileInId  [open $mydir/file.txt r]
set appendLine 0
foreach item $list {
    set j 0
    while {[gets $fileInId line ] != -1} {
        if [regexp  -all -line $item $line] { set appendLine 1 } 
        if $appendLine {
            if [regexp {^\s*\}\s*$} $line] { set appendLine 0 }   
            set line "## $line"    
        }
        puts $line
    }
set j 1
}
```

The result only shows the first entry of the list:

```
Strng00 
Strng021 
Strng02 
Strng03 
Strng_dt 
##Strng01  {
##   some data  
##}

Strng02 
Strng03 
Strng_dt 
Strng42
```

### Strng412

I'd like to get ## after each of the items listed..
Thanks in advance.`

Comment: You're defining a variable with name 'list', which leads to error. Also, I don't get this line:  if [regexp {^\s*\}\s*$} $line] { set appendLine 0 }, do you mind explaining?

Comment: @JudismarJunior: naming a variable "list" won't cause any errors. This is not Scheme.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin, in my interpretor (wish), it causes an error. But I can ignore it for the sake of the answer. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin; Also this is commenting out all line that contain the string.. My bad I didnt mention, but the line must strat with the string as well..

Comment: @Abdi: you should consider the possibility that, with the suggestions you have now, you could solve the rest of the problem yourself. If not, edit your question to reflect the changes in the specification.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin; Thanks!. Your suggestions helped alot!. and that is why i have accepted it as such

Comment: @Peter Lewerin; I have updated the question too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another take:

```
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    set first [lindex [split [string trimleft $line]] 0]
    puts [format "%s%s" [expr {$first in $list ? "##" : ""}] $line]
}
```

That finds the first word in the line, and checks if it is an element in $list.

Comment: Thanks you!. I tested it and it will indeed finds the fiest word

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
set list { Strng01 Strng02 Strng03 Strng_dt Strng42 }
set fileInId  [open $mydir/file.txt r]

while {[gets $fileInId line ] != -1} {
    if {[regexp -line [join $list |] $line]} {
        set line "## $line"    
    }
    puts $line
}
```

---

**edit:** dealing with the updated specification.

This is one way to do it; it takes advantage of the fact that the lines in the file match Tcl command invocation syntax.

```
proc unknown {cmd args} {
    set list { Strng01 Strng02 Strng03 Strng_dt Strng42 }
    if {$cmd in $list} {
        foreach line [split [info level 0] \n] {
            puts "## $line"
        }
    } else {
        puts [info level 0]
    }
}

source file.txt
```

It works like this: using `source` on the file means that the Tcl interpreter tries to use the keywords on each line as command names, with the `{ ... }` parts as arguments. Since the keywords aren't existing commands, the interpreter hands the invocations over to the `unknown` command, which we have redefined to recognize the relevant keywords and print the complete invocation (`[info level 0]`) with a `##` prefix if they are in the list, or else just print the invocation as it is.

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [source](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [unknown](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unknown.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: Great!. thanks this works.. One more question.. I found out that i needed to also comment out some other lines that may come after the strings are found.. for example: Strng01 { some data here } i have tried in the regexp "^${list}\s+\{\s*$\} didnt change much

Comment: You are the best!. got it to work.. doing some post processing since the file isnt strictly tcl based.. Thanks a bunch!